# Python decorator for Django views: Check for a particular setting in UserProfile

Tags: python, django, authentication, decorator

I'd like to write a decorator to use on views all over my site to first check if the logged in user's UserProfile has a particular setting. In my case it's user.get_profile.user_status and the value could be either "expired" or "active". If the user_status = "expired" i want to redirect them to a billing account update page. If they are active, they can pass.

I'd like to be something like `@must_be_active` or `@paywall_check`.

Never wrote a decorator before. Ideas on how best to get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read this http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test

It's actually simpler if you don't write a decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def must_be_active( user ):
    if .... whatever .... 

def paywall_check( user ):
    if .... whatever .... 

@user_passes_test(must_be_active)
def my_view(request):
    do the work

@user_pass_test(paywall_check)
def another_view(request):
    do the work
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, instead of applying this to views, I applied this technique to my urls.py where other, similar settings are present. It makes better sense to me to have them here. After your answer, this related blog post helped as well: http://jonatkinson.co.uk/djangos-user_passes_test-and-generic-views/

Answer (score 0):

Short direct example

http://www.djangofoo.com/tag/custom-decorator